# BigQuery Service Account can query public datasets under my account

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to create a GCP service account that is allowed to query only a specific dataset. I'm very close to having the configuration correct, but even a service account with just the "BigQuery Job User" role can run queries against the BigQuery public datasets, incurring usage on my project. I do not want to allow this.

My goal is to provide key customers with access to their analytical data only, without allowing them to run queries against the public datasets and rack up usage under my project.

Edit: I've rearranged some permissions and removed all project-level roles. Now my service account only has two dataset roles:

- BigQuery Data Viewer
- BigQuery Metadata Viewer

They can run jobs against my dataset, but they still can also run jobs against the public BigQuery dataset.

[image]

Comment: The key is to grant access control at the dataset level and not the project level: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#dataset_level However, usage will be billed under your project. I am not sure about billing for public datasets.

Comment: Interesting question .... looking here ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.jobUser

Either a user can run a Job in a project or they can't ... IF they can run a job, then they can charge/spend against your project.   Solutions:  1.  Constrain the queries they can run ... don't let them run arbitrary queries.   2. Have your customers run queries in THEIR projects and the charges/spends are their responsibility.   The problem would NOT be just public datasets ... it would be ANY datasets/tables that they can query

Comment: @Kolban Thanks, but I don't mind paying for charges that they incur running queries against our private datasets. So the question is not about how to get my customers to pay for their usage, rather it's how do I restrict the usage only to what I am willing to pay for. I only mentioned costs because that's the justification for restricting the usage.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am granting access to the service account at the dataset level only but the service account can still run queries against the public datasets.

Comment: I am unaware of a method to prevent users from querying public datasets. However, please do not take my comment as an answer because I don't know. However, your design might be flawed. Do not give users a service account. Instead, implement authorization in your application. You can then fine-grain control over which resources they can access. A service account should only be given to trusted users. It is not a general purpose authorization mechanism.

Comment: @JohnHanley Google documentation states that this is the recommended approach for multi-tenant SaaS vendors and customers. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-for-multi-tenant-workloads-on-bigquery#saas-dedicated

Answer (score 1):

According to this google cloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#dataset_level):

> ***When you assign roles at the organization and project level, you provide permission to run BigQuery jobs or to access all of a project's BigQuery resources. You can assign roles at the dataset level to provide access to a specific dataset, without providing complete access to the project's resources.***

Based on my understanding, for your requirement you can consider dataset sharing in the bigQuery. You can follow the below steps to share a dataset.

**Step1**: Go to the BigQuery page.

**Step2**: In the Explorer panel, expand your project and select a dataset.

**Step3**: Click Share -> Permissions.

**Step4**: Click  Add principal.

**Step5**: In the New principals field, enter a principal.

**Step6**: For data access only,choose the BigQuery Data Viewer role.

**Step7**: Click Save.

For more information  and workaround refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam#console_2),[link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-datasets) and [link3](https://mbha-phoenix.medium.com/the-subtle-art-of-sharing-views-in-bigquery-7fc553cb9e77).

Comment: Nice answer. Typo for missing step 4?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley,Thanks :D

Comment: Hi @kiranmathew, this is basically what I've done. I've granted the "BigQuery Data Viewer" and "BigQuery Metadata Viewer" roles from the dataset to my service account, but the service account still has access to run queries against public datasets.

Comment: The way I interpret the question is how do we prevent:

SELECT * FROM bigquery-public-data.dataset.table

These are tables which are public and hence have no restriction.   If a user is granted BigQuery Job User they they are allowed to run JOBS in a project ... what I think the OP is asking is how to restrict a user from ONLY running jobs that refer to permitted tables.  The recipe doesn't seem to restrict jobs from running against public tables and hence incurring charges.

Comment: Hi @Clark McCauley,can you take a look at these [link1](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/EFNF54m8R5o) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50827725/17258510).Some workaround is also mentioned here.